# runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x602000000390 overflowed to 0x60200000038c

Tags: overflow

I was solving a question named as. Find First and Last Position of Element in Sorted Array
'''

```
void bin_search(vector<int>&nums,int target,int l,int  h,int &a,int &b)
{
   if(l>h)
       return;

   int  mid= l + (h - l) / 2;

if(nums[mid]==target)
{
   
    if(nums[mid-1]==target)
    {
     
    bin_search(nums,target,l,mid-1,a,b);
    }
    else
    {
        a=mid;
    }

     if(nums[mid+1]==target)
    {
     
    bin_search(nums,target,mid+1,h,a,b);
    }
    else 
    {
        b=mid;
    }
   
}
else if(nums[mid]<target)
{
bin_search(nums,target,mid+1,h,a,b);

}
else 
{
     bin_search(nums,target,l,mid-1,a,b);
}
}

class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> searchRange(vector<int>& nums, int target) {
        
        int a=-1;
        int b=-1;
        int l=0;
        int h=nums.size()-1;
        bin_search(nums,target,l,h,a,b);
        
        return {a,b};
    }
};
```

'''
this is the code which i submitted but i am getting
Line 1034: Char 34: runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x602000000390 overflowed to 0x60200000038c (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../include/c++/10/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:34
error i am able to pass all the test cases in my complier and other id but didn't able to solve this bug
please help me thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please add the link to the question?

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/find-first-and-last-position-of-element-in-sorted-array